# Is it possible to use e.which with .click?

Tags: jquery, click

I would like to know if it is possible to set up something like

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if(e.which == $('#target') {
        //execute code
    }
});
```

Meaning that I have all click events inside one function with if statements finding out where the user clicked. I would like to do it this way for my active scrolling on a site because the code would be cleaner.

Comment: `e.which` contains the key/mousebutton which is clicked, you are looking for [e.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Comment: @empiric so that code would work if I used e.target?

Comment: @Shniper It is a valid technique to put the listener on the document as you suggest. Why do you think it will be bad ? (Implied by your asking)

Comment: You can't compare objects in JS, so you'd need to compare properties of the objects, eg. their ids:
 `e.target.id == 'target'`

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I think it will be better for readability if I handle clicks by category inside of functions instead of having them all inside the document ready function

Comment: @Shniper: What do you mean "by category"?  Are you just looking to create a delegated/"live" event: `$(document).on('click', '#target', function(){});`?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki: `this` would wind up being `document` (as that's what the event is *actually* bound to).

Comment: @RocketHazmat here is a jsfiddle of my code, if that helps you understand my reasoning https://jsfiddle.net/w99zrrLt/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan please make an answer with what you said so I can accept it as correct. It worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a key reference to a jQuery object.

```
e.which == $('#target')
```

You can use is

```
$("#target").is(e.target)
```

you can compare ids

```
e.target.id === "target"
```

or you can use what jQuery has build in for event delegation

```
$(document).on("click", "#target", function(){ });
```

Comment: @empiric whoops, copied and pasted from original and forgot to swap out target. I need more coffee.

Comment: I like the suggestion of `$("#target").is(e.target)`

Answer (score 3):

You've to use `e.target` that refer to the current clicked object instead of `e.which`, then get the `id` and compare it with the targeted id `target` , try :

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var target_id = 'target';

    if(e.target.id == target_id) {
        //execute code
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  var target_id = 'target';

  if(e.target.id == target_id) {
    console.log('Target clicked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Div 1</div>
<div>Div 2</div>
<div id='target'>Div 3</div>
<div>Div 4</div>
```

Comment: Sorry Zakaria, this won't work as you cannot compare objects directly in JS (https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/1cxw5wxg/). You would need to evaluate them using the properties of the object.

Comment: You're right @Rory. updated my asnwer to compare the id's instead.

Comment: I'd suggest `e.target.id` instead of `$(e.target).prop('id')`.